# Custom WP theme not showing shortcodes

Tags: shortcode

I'm building a custom theme and am trying to use the Nivo Slider wordpress plug in. I have a widget area under my nav bar and for some reason only the shortcode shows, not the slider. I have read that I need to have "the_content();" in there, but it still doesn't work. Can anyone give me pointers? Here is my index.php.

By the way I know other widgets work in this area. I've also tried another slideshow plug in that uses shortcode. It didn't work either.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">

    <?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <article> 
        <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

        <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> </h2></div><!-- End col-md-8 -->
             <div class="col-md-4"><small><p class="text-muted pull-right"><?php the_time('l, F jS, Y')?></p></small></div> <!-- End col-md-4 -->
             </div>  <!-- End row -->
           </div>
<?php the_content(); ?>


                <a  class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">Read More</a>

</article>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?> 

  </div> <!-- End col-md-9 -->
  <div class="col-md-3"><div class="well">

<?php include("sidebar.php"); ?>

 </div><!-- End well -->
 </div>  <!-- End col-md-3 -->
</div><!-- End row -->
  </div><!-- End col-md-12 -->
</div> <!-- End row -->
<div class="spacer"></div>
</div><!-- End Container -->


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: p.s. I've tried using a default theme and no luck. Only shortcode text displays. Disabling all plug ins didn't help either.

Comment: Just an update... I tried another shortcode plug in, not a slideshow one, and it works. Perhaps just some weird bug with two slider plug ins? I am contacting support for one of them to see what they say.

Answer (score 0):

The other shortcode plugin probably includes this code:

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
```

If you add this to your theme's functions.php, the shortcodes might render?

Comment: I wish, but no luck with that.